# caesar cypher decryptor

Tags: c++, encryption

Alright so I have been "Tasked" with writing a program to decrypt the simple caesar cyphers.

I have everything working correctly, only my input stops about 29 characters in. It's reading from a very large file and the text stops at: "the declaration of independe" mid sentence. Any ideas what could cause this? I"m assuming I'm abusing and misusing something here. Feel free to throw rocks at my head. I'm sure I could use more "learning"

EDIT: upon further investigation I believe my issue is to do with my loops and sizeof(myarray)

edit 2: I've edited the code and now it breaks because of **"Access violation reading location 0x002A4000":**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++)
    {
        // pritns each occurance cout << char(i + 'a') << " has " << count_Array[i] <<" occuarnces"  <<endl;
        if (count_Array[i] > tester)
        {
            //finds largest 
            tester = count_Array[i];
            max_array_value = i;
        }
    }
    // print

Thanks for any tips :] 

code: 

   #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int decipher(string myArray, string outputFileName);

int main ()
{ 
    string outputFileName;
    string inputFileName;
    ifstream inputFile;
    string reply;
    char myArray;
    string all_text = "";

    //getting input and output files
    cout << "Please input filename: ";
    getline(cin,inputFileName);
    cout <<"please enter output filename:";
    getline(cin,outputFileName);
    //opens file
    inputFile.open(inputFileName);

    if (!inputFile.is_open())
    {
        //file failed to open
        cout <<"unable to open input file." <<endl << "Press enter to continue...";
        getline(cin,reply);
        exit(1);
    }
    //read file into all_text
    while(inputFile.peek() != EOF)
    {
        inputFile.get(myArray);
            all_text+=myArray;

    }
    // prints out file cout <<all_text;
            inputFile.close();
            //send to decipher
            decipher(all_text, outputFileName);
    cout << "press enter to continue";
    getline(cin,reply);
    return 0;
}



int decipher(string myArray, string outputFileName)
{
    char default_alp[26] = {'a', 'b' ,'c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
    int count_Array[26] = { 0 };
    int tester = count_Array[0];
    int max_array_value = 0;
    string my_Message;
    char temp;
    ofstream outputFile;
    //gets count of occurances
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++)
    {
        count_Array[tolower(myArray[i]) - 'a']++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++)
    {
        // pritns each occurance cout << char(i + 'a') << " has " << count_Array[i] <<" occuarnces"  <<endl;
        if (count_Array[i] > tester)
        {
            //finds largest 
            tester = count_Array[i];
            max_array_value = i;

        }
    }
    // prints useful information cout << "Largest number of occurances " << default_alp[max_array_value] <<endl << "shift amount is: " << default_alp[max_array_value]-'e' <<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++)
    {
//prints out each letter    cout << myArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        cout <<myArray.length();
        //shifts the text based on value in dec
        int shift = default_alp[max_array_value]-'e';
        temp = myArray[i];
        if (isalpha(temp))
        {
            if(tolower(myArray[i])-shift >= 97)
            {
                my_Message += tolower(myArray[i]) - shift;
            }
            else
            {
                my_Message += tolower(myArray[i]) + 26-shift;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                my_Message +=myArray[i];
        }
    }
    outputFile.open(outputFileName);
    outputFile << my_Message;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, your usage of `sizeof` is incorrect. It is not applicable here, use `.length()`. Your other error is that you don't check `isalpha` when you index your letters array. There may be more errors.

Comment: Yeah I just moved them to .length(). working on the other error now. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What compiler are you using. For me, it does not compile because

//opens file
    inputFile.open(inputFileName);

needs to be
//opens file
    inputFile.open(inputFileName.c_str());

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/

but when it does compile, things seem to work ok. The whole file is read.

Comment: read yes, but it stops early on the output. It would appear to be related to my use of Sizeof(myarray);however, when i transfer it to myArray.Length() the code breaks with: handled exception at 0x013F828E in a06.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x002A4000.

Comment: sizeof(string) == sizeof(myarray) it does not matter how large the string is. you might want to use myarray.length() . Try this:

Comment: myarray.length = 1000 count_array[1000] leads to access violation.

Comment: HAHA! Thanks for pointing that out. That did it... That explains a lot.. I replaced it with a more appropriate array length ( of size 26) ;) I can't beleive I missed that. Thanks for all the other feedback!

Answer (score 1):

In `decipher`, `sizeof(myArray)` gives you the size of a `string` instance. The `string` instance may contain the actual length of the string, some space for very small strings and a pointer to the actual data, but it does not contain the data, i.e. the string, itself.

Instead of `sizeof(myArray)`, use `myArray.length()`!

Comment: yeah I made that changes minutes after posting this because I realized what I was doing, the code just didn't decide to update.